# Network error while fetching gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle, bundler

I added gem to my Gemfile:  `'itunes-search-api', '~> 0.1.0'`.
And tried to install it using `bundle install --retry 4`

But I've got an error:

```
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies...
Network error while fetching https://aws-eu-cache01.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/sys-uname-0.9.2-universal-mingw32.gemspec.rz
```

Comment: try gem update bundler

Comment: @AydarOmurbekov without success. I've got an error: 
`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::SpecificGemNotFoundException)
    Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (= 1.7.9) locally or in a repository
`